# OpenCV: Descriptor matching with predefined constraints

Tags: python, opencv

I have a bunch of keypoints on `leftImage` and `rightImage`. Given that the camera can move only horizontally, how can I efficiently find the distance moved by the camera horizontally?

I believe, using `homographyMatrix, __ = cv2.findHomography(pointsRight, pointsLeft, cv2.RANSAC)` would be just a  waste of computation, and not only that, there is no guarantee that the final homography matrix would only translate horizontally.

Or in other words, if I know the homography matrix can only be

```
[ 1 0 x
  0 1 0
  0 0 1 ]
```

how do I find x given keypoints and descriptors?